# ruby on rails - formtastic - form class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I have a form built with formtastic, the code is

```
<%= semantic_form_for @plan, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal" } do |form|%>
    <%= form.input :name %>
    [..some inputs here...]
    <%= form.buttons%>
<%end%>
```

but the form isn't getting the class "form-horizontal", the generated code is

```
<form id="new_plan" class="formtastic plan" novalidate="novalidate" method="post" action="/plans" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    [...inputs/actions...]
</form>
```

Why?

I'm using formtastic 2.1, gemfile:

```
gem 'formtastic', :git => 'https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic.git', :branch => "2.1-stable"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap your html options in another hash

```
<%= semantic_form_for @plan, {:html => { :class => "form-horizontal" }} do |form|%>
```

It dose seem weird but I had that problem before, and the above solved it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great. Would you mind accepting this if it helped you? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, sorry but this was my 1st question on SO.